# Cross domain Remote debugging on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: remote-debugging

I have 2 machines :

**Developer machine**(running the VS 2008): connected to network **abc.lan** & VPN **xyz.lan**

**Remote machine**(running the service):    connected to VPN **xyz.lan**

On the developer machine, when I goto Debug->Attach to process->Browse(for Qualifier), only the machines which are on abc.lan are visible BUT NOT the remote machine which is connected only on VPN xyz.lan

Is there a way by which the remote machine could be visible across the domain ?

PS : In general, any guideline to do the same would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly attach the remote machine process to debugger, if connected through VPN or Remote Desktop. Instead you can do the following if you have rights there

1. Install WinDbg with symbols
2. Use Reflector with Deblector
3. Install VS on the same machine, access it through RDP or VPN and debug

Answer (score 0):

You can remote debug across domains, but you'll have to enter either the IP Address or the machine name in manually. There are some restrictions, such as needing to use a Local User account instead of a domain account. This MSDN article specifically details it out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y5b4b4f(v=vs.90).aspx